# How to clone a product programatically in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, php

I have to create a clone product programmatically in Magento2. Below code (based on Magento1 answers in this forum does not work).

```
$newproduct =   $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$newproduct->load(10);
$clone = $newproduct->duplicate();
```

I don't see any `duplicate()` method in `Product` class. Any help/pointers?

Answer (score 4):

please use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier $productCopier
) {
    $this->productCopier = $productCopier;
} 

public function copySomeProduct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product  $originalProduct) {
   $copiedProduct = $this->productCopier->copy($originalProduct);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$oldProduct = $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$newProduct = $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$oldProduct->load(10);
$newProduct->SetData($oldProduct->getData());
$newProduct->save();
```

Ofcourse, you will run into duplicate key issues but all it takes is to override key attributes like SKU, URL_KEY etc.

Comment: This does not work when the product contains images. I get the folowing error:  [Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException]
  The image content is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$copier = $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\CopyConstructorFactory');
$oldProduct = $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'); $oldProduct->load(10);
$newProduct = $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$copier->build($oldProduct, $newProduct);
```

I didn't tried it, but I'm sure that CopyConstructor is for duplicating products.

Good luck!

Comment: CopyConstructorFactory does not have any build() method. It has only one method:
`public function create($instance, array $arguments = [])
    {
        if (!is_subclass_of($instance, '\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\CopyConstructorInterface')) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                $instance . ' does not implement \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\CopyConstructorInterface'
            );
        }

        return $this->objectManager->create($instance, $arguments);
    }
`

Not sure if I can use it..

Comment: You're right, class responsible for it is \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier. I tried to use it, but i haven't succeed. If you will, please share an answer. Check it implementation in Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Duplicate maybe it will help

Comment: Have you solved that problem with the CopyConstructorInterface?
I also can't instantiate the Copier Class.